# Three.js Orbitcontrols issue with colladaloader2

Tags: three.js, collada

When I load a .dae file in a scene with colladaloader (first one with the 2 behind it) it works all OK except that transparent objects aren't shown as transparent, the controls work like the OrbitControls should work.

But when I try to change the colladaloader 1 to the 2 version it loads all objects and the threejs scene is fine but the controls are like trackballcontrols.

If you need an example, I can make one.

Answer (score 0):

i found out, that on colladaloader 1 the object isn't correctly converted to its position, so i repositioned it by rotation.x to 4.70.

on the loader2 i didn't had to do this and it also fixed my problem!